# Regex match comma when condition is met

Tags: javascript, regex, negative-lookbehind

Currently, I have a problem with matching comma in some conditions.

for example

`<product_11,product_12>=5,product_1,product_2,product_3=1,product_9=3,<product_5,product_6>=10,product_11,product_12,product_13,product_14=20`

I don't want to match that comma when there is `=\d+` and inside `<>`,  so, in this case, the comma that I want to match is only from `product_1,product_2,product_3` and `product_11,product_12,product_13,product_14=20`.

Actually, I have already done the code and it works fine, but as I knew the code is only for ECMAScript 2018 compliant environments and it doesn't support browsers like Mozilla, ie, etc

Here is my regex code.

```
(?<!\s*[=]\s*\d+)\,\s?(?![^\<]*\>)
```

https://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/231

Are there any other options to match the comma that I expect?

I want to replace the matching comma to `/`

so the output will be

```
<product_11,product_12>=5,product_1/product_2/product_3=1,product_9=3,<product_5,product_6>=10,product_11/product_12/product_13/product_14=20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and a callback function for [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

In the alternation you can match what you want and what you don't want. In the replace function you can check if the match is a single comma and replace that with a forward slash.

```
<[^<>]+>|=\d+,|,
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/50RKwi/1)

For example:

```js
let pattern = /<[^<>]+>|=\d+,|,/g;
let str = `<product_11,product_12>=5,product_1,product_2,product_3=1,product_9=3,<product_5,product_6>=10,product_11,product_12,product_13,product_14=20`;
str = str.replace(pattern, function($m) {
  return $m === "," ? '/' : $m;
});
console.log(str);
```

Comment: hello, I want to ask how to do this replace in php?

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is not a single regexp this may be what you need:

```
s.replace(/(<[^>]*>)/g,'\n$1\n')
 .split('\n')
 .map(x=> /</.test(x)?x:x.replace(/(_\d+),/g,"$1/"))
 .join('')
```

For s:

```
s = '<product_11,product_12>=5,product_1,product_2,product_3=1,product_9=3,<product_5,product_6>=10,product_11,product_12,product_13,product_14=20'
```

This expression returns:

```
"<product_11,product_12>=5,product_1/product_2/product_3=1,product_9=3,<product_5,product_6>=10,product_11/product_12/product_13/product_14=20"
```

​

Comment: hello, I have updated the question and show the output.. could you have a check for expected output?

Comment: there is a condition when the value of `product` doesn't have `_` so it is not working and when I modified your script from `(_\d+)` to `\d+` it replaced all the comma except in `<>` here is the output
 
`<product_11,product_12>=5/product_1/product_2/product_3=1/product_9=3/<product_5,product_6>=10/product_11/product_12/product_13/product_14=20`

Comment: for clearance, when the condition is `\=\d+\,`  don't replace the comma.